# css help , to create div

Tags: css

Please see pic, this is what I want to do. I am really struggling to bloody do it lol.
[image]

The master div, is 600px wide ( blue bg ) and need splitting into two areas, left for the image and right for the text etc.
Ignore the vertical divider line

The left hand div, is approx 200px wide, and need to specify a min-height of 100px, as the placeholder image which is centered to that div 50% 50% will change size, as I will be adding another div like this with larger image placeholder.

The right part contains the header tag, description, button and second description.

I have already constructed this and works fine in chrome and ff, but not in ie. So could you guys have a think, and give me some code that complies in all browsers.

It is officially doing my head in now.

Screenpic of it working in ff and chrome below:
[image]

Comment: Have you considered posting your html and css? Or maybe (*also*) posting a demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631425/css-help-needed-to-fix-issue-in-ie For some reason link didnt appear in original question above

Answer (score 0):

You're probably experiencing either a margin or float bug in ie. It's hard to say without seeing any code, but this link has always helped me when it comes to debugging IE.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/

And yes, this question could be formatted much better.

Comment: Cheers: I did post link to my other SO question, but it didnt appear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631425/css-help-needed-to-fix-issue-in-ie